# Disambiguate or combine tags for [city] and [urban-riding]

Tags: discussion, tagging

Most (but not all) of the questions tagged [city](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city) are about [urban-riding](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urban-riding) (and indeed some of them are cross-tagged).

The exceptions seem to be:

- Some questions about city bikes

  - (Not to be confused with [citi-bike](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citi-bike) NYC bike rental, which some people [clearly already do](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/64804/33084).)
- A few questions about bike security in the city
- A question about what makes a city a good place to bike
- Questions where [city](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city) is incidental, but unnecessary

Can a consensus be reached on what [city](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city) should be for, and then (if appropriate) merge with [urban-riding](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urban-riding)?

Answer (score 1):

https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city  shows a wide variety of questions, some are related to riding in cities or urban environments, some aren't.

https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urban-riding By comparison, is pretty solid with results about riding and parking in the urban areas.

Neither have a precis to show what was intended by the tag creator.

Answer (score 1):

Urban-riding has me thinking Urban Freeride or Urban MTBing, with associated social media videos of crashes. City has me thinking people closer to my age commuting to work or riding like mere mortals with the aim of getting from A to B.

With no guidance on the Urban-riding tag, it is perfectly reasonable for people to associate it with the latter. Without that guidance, no one can really know what the tags were intended and cannot expect tags to be used in a consistent way.

Merging Urban Riding with City (as a vast majority of these questions are what I perceive as city riding), and create a new tag Urban-Freeride (if we do not already have one).